# Changin CSS in View from Router.js file Express JS

Tags: javascript, express

Is it possible to access a element in the view from a router in expressjs.  For instance, could I access the view and change the following code from the router in ExpressJS?

```
<div id="I would like to be accessed from the router">
    <p>This is the index page and I am attached to an index router</p>
</div>


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var document.get...("I would like to be accessed from the router");

    res.render('NOOOOYOUCANT!!!', { title: 'Why can't I access the view?'});
});
```

Why can't I access the css in the view from the router?

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I access the css in the view from the router?

You are trying to access client side variables from the server.  Unless you have passed this data from the **client** (View) to the **server** (Node.js), the server will not be able to access the view's data.

The router does not know about the view.

What you can do is issue an [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`Form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) request from the view to the router.

Comment: Hey thanks so to be clear it's impossible to do it the way I am trying to do it because the router doesn't know about the view. Thank you.